# Unicode 'OBJECT REPLACEMENT CHARACTER'  added to start of first li in firefox

Tags: jquery, firefox, html-lists

I'm guessing iv done something in jquery
works fine in safari but when i load in firefox it appends a weird obj string in a dotted box in front of all first li's

can someone please explain why it is there / tell me how to get rid of it

the only jquery on the page is a testimonial rotator i wrote:

```
<script>     
  var count = 1;  
  var quote = $("ul#quotes li");
  var total = quote.size();
  quote.hide()
  quote.filter(':nth-child(1)').fadeIn()                   
  window.setInterval(function(){
 quote.fadeOut()    
 .delay(500)
 count++;
 if (count > total) { count = 1; }
 quote.filter(':nth-child(' + count + ')').fadeIn()     
  }, 5000);
</script>
```

site is:
http://toukleywindowcleaning.com.au/

html as requested:

```
<div id="colTwo">
   <div id="reasons">
      <ul>
            <li>￼5 REASONS WHY PEOPLE CHOOSE US</li>
            <li>10 years experience</li>
            <li>Fully Insured</li>
            <li>All care taken for carpet & furnishings</li>
            <li>We turn up on time</li>
            <li>100% satisfaction guaranteed</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

OK as everyone is saying its not Jquery what is it? its not in my code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This has nothing to do with your jquery code.  if you view the source, the 'obj' is actually a special character that already exists in your HTML.

You can verify this by disabling javascript in your browser.

Check whatever is generating your HTML.. seems it is trying to render something that isnt a string.

Comment: yeah weird but if i check it in safari or Crome the character is not there

Comment: It's a non-printing character, so each browser can handle its implementation differently.  Its the unicode object replacement character http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/fffc/index.htm

Comment: The thing that looks like a space in front of the 5 is not a space.  I'm not sure where it would of come from, but delete it.

Comment: its not in my source to delete could it be because I'm using :first-child in my css?

Comment: Its definitely in your html source.  Your editor may not be able to see it.  Delete the whole First LI and see what happens.  Try manually re-typing the first LI

Comment: it was a zen coding plugin for coda the character was actually part of the <li> tag

Answer (score 0):

The strange symbol is hard-coded (in two places) in the HTML.

It has nothing to do with the javascript/jQuery.

Comment: Very strange. Try suppressing the CSS first-child directive temporarily to eliminate it. If that doesn't fix it, then try retyping the two characters on either side of where the symbol appears to eliminate the possibility that some bad unicode character managed to sneak into your HTML source at some stage. Use Notepad or Notepad++; certainly not MS Word. After that, I can only think that your server is dynamically inserting the symbol but how/why I cannot begin to imagine.

Answer (score 0):

I copy and pasted it from some other document and it just picked up some blind characters. I re-typed it and it's gone.